# Show a System Tray notification or Desktop notification from the web application

Tags: java, swing, notifications

I have created a web application in Java using J2EE 6.0 that has login functionality. As the user logs in into the application, a timer start at 59:59 (minutes:seconds) and keeps on decreasing until it comes to 3:00. When 3 minutes are left, it displays a **popup** to the user asking to **logout** or **extend their time/session** again back to 59:59.

My question is if user is doing some other work say on outlook or surfing some other thing over the internet in a new window/browser(Firefox,etc.). How can I notify the user that his session/time is going to expire. This application is intended to run only on  Microsoft Windows **Internet Explorer**.

I found these links for displaying desktop notifications but unfortunately my application is specific to run on Internet Explorer only

[What ways are out there to display a desktop notification from a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092885/what-ways-are-out-there-to-display-a-desktop-notification-from-a-web-app)

[How do Stack Overflow desktop notifications work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594620/how-do-stack-overflow-desktop-notifications-work)

**So I cannot use Desktop notifications.**

I thought I would create a **swing application** to display the notification popup in the Windows System Tray saying 'Your session is going to expire'. But I am stucked how will it run on the client machine.
I have heard of something called **Java Web Start**, **AjaxSwing**, etc.
With **Java Web Start** software, users can launch a Java application by clicking a link in a web page. It requires JRE in the client system. Java Web Start will ask the user to download the **Java plugin** which will download a JRE(if not found in the client's system) which is annoying.

**AjaxSwing** will convert the Swing app to HTML, Javascript and CSS so I am not sure how it will come out of a browser to show up a popup in System Tray. I think that will remain stick to the browser.

I searched for blinking the tab option but it is not blinking the tab in the taskbar of the windows.

I read somewhere **Growl for Windows** but I am not sure whether it will be helpful for me or not. Please tell that also.
Please suggest me how can I notify the user that his session is going to expire. I already know I can notify through the **email**. Please help me with an innovative idea and solution to pursue further.

Comment: Can anybody please help me in this problem? I need some valuable suggestions please help. I thought atleast one person might have faced this problem. Please suggest something

Comment: It seems nobody has answer to this question since it's almost two months and no one has commented on this post.
If anybody has faced this kind of issue or they know a better alternative, please share your suggestions. I am open to all.

Comment: I believe you haven't gotten the response you are looking for because it's not possible AFAIK. The browser will sandbox all the client-side apps, there is no communication allowed across that boundary. I think the workaround is to have an additional stand-alone wondows application downloaded and installed by the user (like growl for windows) which can register events and/or query your login server for the info you want and display popups from the system tray.

Comment: @2manyprojects- Thanks for the answer but I cannot ask the user to install a stand-alone app just for the purpose of notification. Thanks for your valuable answer !

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and used [jquery notification plugin](http://ned.im/noty/#/about)  as a workaround you can also use "onShow" in the plugin callback to play a sound or whatever to make sure that the user is notified

Comment: HI Mohamed, I already visited this link. This will work for current window/tab. I want something through which I can notify the user that his session is going to expire even if he is not using the browser and working on some other windows application. I hope I cleared my question to you

Answer (score 0):

try it for Google Chrome:

```
function notifyBrowser(title, desc, url) {
    if (Notification.permission !== "granted") {
        Notification.requestPermission();
    } else {
        var notification = new Notification(title, {
            icon: 'http://YourWebsite.com/logo.png',
            body: desc,
        });
        /* Remove the notification from Notification Center when clicked.*/
        notification.onclick = function() {
            window.open(url);
        };
        /* Callback function when the notification is closed. */
        notification.onclose = function() {
            console.log('Notification closed');
        };
    }
}
```

And so, only call the function :

`notifyBrowser('Pay attention', 'You have new notifications', 'www.stackoverflow.com');`

font: http://www.9lessons.info/2015/11/display-browser-notifications-from-web.html