# Lock entire browser with a popup

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, popup

I didn't find any answer to my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825117/show-a-system-tray-notification-or-desktop-notification-from-the-web-application) question, probably it's not possible at all. So I am posting a different question with an example of HP Quality Center.

Is it possible just like HP Quality Center to lock the entire browser when the session expires. QC window pops up on front of all the windows in the browser and it doesn't allow the user to click anywhere until the user cancels the popup or re-enter the password and click sign-in.

Your valuable suggestions will be very helpful for me.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Sounds really annoying.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a UI blocking popup (with a login form, for example)?

Comment: @SLaks Worth noting for interop purposes that [`showModalDialog` doesn't have too promising a future](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.showModalDialog) cross-browser.

Comment: @JackZelig - No, I am looking for something which can block the entire browser. If you worked on QC, then you have must have seen this functionality

Comment: @jeffamaphone - Actually I am looking for a popup which should be displayed when the user's session expires and he is working on some other tab. It should automatically lock the browser through a popup and unless he sign out/ extend session the popup shouldn't allow anything to do